# What does "as may be" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Your personal data is governed by any privacy policy which may be in
>   effect on the Site from time-to-time, as may be amended from
>   time-to-time.

I read this from a terms of use. What does "as may be" mean? Does this mean:

> ... is governed by the privacy policy which may be in effect on the
>   Site from time-to-time. This privacy policy may be amended from
>   time-to-time.

Or

> ... is governed by the privacy policy which may be in effect on the
>   Site from time-to-time when this privacy policy is amended from
>   time-to-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think splitting it into two sentences makes the meaning clearer.

> Your personal data is governed by any privacy policy which may be in effect on the Site from time-to-time.
>
> [Those privacy policies which may be in effect from time-to-time] may be amended from time-to-time.